# How can I access the network of a container?

Tags: docker, podman

I am sure this was asked a million times but I just cannot find anything online for some reason.

I have two network I created with Podman (similar to Docker).

When I do localhost:9998 it just times out.

So it just can't connect.

Is there a way to create net bridge so that I can curl my container in a specific container network?

**UPDATE**

```
[
{
    "cniVersion": "0.4.0",
    "name": "search",
    "plugins": [
        {
            "bridge": "cni-podman0",
            "ipMasq": true,
            "ipam": {
                "ranges": [
                    [
                        {
                            "gateway": "10.89.0.1",
                            "subnet": "10.89.0.0/24"
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "routes": [
                    {
                        "dst": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "host-local"
            },
            "isGateway": true,
            "type": "bridge"
        },
        {
            "capabilities": {
                "portMappings": true
            },
            "type": "portmap"
        },
        {
            "backend": "iptables",
            "type": "firewall"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `podman inspect <container-name>` to get the IP Address of the container.

This command here returns just the IP address:

```
podman inspect <container-name> --format '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}'
```

Comment: Doesn't work: Error: Template parsing error: template: image:1:18: executing "image" at <.NetworkSettings.IPA...>: can't evaluate field NetworkSettings in type *inspect.ImageData

Answer (score 0):

From what I was reading I needed to get the gateway IP from `podman network inspect search`

It was: 10.89.0.1

When I CURL that IP it still didn't work.

But then I found this in the IPtables :

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
...

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
CNI-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* CNI firewall plugin rules */

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
...        

 Chain CNI-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
...
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.89.0.20           ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.89.0.20           anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.89.1.2            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.89.1.2            anywhere            

...
```

The IPs 10.89.0.20 and 10.89.1.2 are the IPs for my host to have access to each of the podman networks.